# Is there an easy way to enable Tk for Ruby in OS X v10.6+?

Tags: ruby, macos, tk-toolkit

Starting with Snow Leopard (OS X v10.6) Apple bundles 64-bit ruby by default. Unfortunately, there is no 64-bit Tk bundled, so the following ruby code will fail:

```
require 'tk'
```

Is it some easy way to enable Tk for Ruby in Snow Leopard and higher? Like installing 32-bit ruby or whatever. I have tried to recompile Ruby with Tk support but it seems not that easy - tutorials found in google refers to some options in Ruby's `./configure` script that don't exists in actual Rby code downloaded from official site :(. I will be glad for any hints - i have a Ruby app with Tk GUI and need to enable my users to use it :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where was a great improvement over Tk documentation recently. Not they has [complete instructions](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html) on how to enable Tk for Ruby on OSX 10.6+. This requires ActiveTcl 8.5+ binary distribution and compiling ruby from source. The command i used on OSX 10.7 with XCode 4.2 to compile ruby and replace stock ruby installation (dangerous!):

```
./configure --prefix=/usr --with-arch=x86_64,i386 --enable-pthread --enable-shared --with-gcc=clang
make
sudo make install
```

Answer (score 1):

Tk builds fine in 64-bit mode on OSX, but only if you've got sources from the 8.6 series[<sup>«ZIP»</sup>](https://core.tcl.tk/tk/zip/Tk%20Source%20Code-00dce1f0e6a4705c.zip?uuid=00dce1f0e6a4705c30c8a3a8dd9e1db52d03e73a)[<sup>«TGZ»</sup>](https://core.tcl.tk/tk/tarball/Tk%20Source%20Code-00dce1f0e6a4705c.tar.gz?uuid=00dce1f0e6a4705c30c8a3a8dd9e1db52d03e73a) (still in beta for various reasons, but quite usable). You'll want to ensure you configure with `--enable-aqua --enable-64bit` of course, but I assume that's pretty much obvious.

(Alas, I can't say how to then integrate the build of Tk with your Ruby installation, though there is [some documentation online](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/install.html) that seems to be somewhat relevant. I emphasize that I've only googled for it though; on this I don't speak from experience.)

Comment: Unfortunately, i can't build Tk in Snow Leopard. `./configure --enable-aqua --enable-64bit && make` leads to `tkMacOSXBitmap.c:262: error 'CIconHandle' undeclared`

Comment: Which version are you using? You need the version I pointed to so that it is using Cocoa on the back end, not the old versions that use Carbon. (`CIconHandle` is a Carbon thing.) For the record, I've been using cocoa-based builds for about 2 years now…